# cat displays multi-line file content in a single line

Tags: linux, bash, concatenation, logfile

In Linux Shell script, I am trying to trace each command status (either Success or Failure) in a log file.

Below is my code snippet to log the entries in a log file.

```
scp $user@$host:$from $to 2>error.txt

command_run_status=$?

if [[ $command_run_status == 0 ]]; then log_message="secure copy on ("${host}") with ("${user}") is successful"; else log_message="error copying files "`cat error.txt`; fi

./logging.sh "$CURRENT_PID" "$log_message" "D"
```

Log file is created with an entry as below:

```
DEBUG 2019-06-21 10:05:35,347 BST [pid1234] [autouser]: error copying files usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2
```

However, I am expecting the log entry as below - error.txt file content with new line character.

```
DEBUG 2019-06-21 10:05:35,347 BST [pid1234] [autouser]: error copying files

usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]

           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]

           [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Content of error.txt is as below:

```
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]

           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]

           [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Can someone comment on the cause of displaying multi-line file content are displaying in a single line in the log file?

What changes are required on the command to print the error file content (with newline character) in the log file?

Comment: Could you post your `logging.sh` script?

Comment: BTW, backtick-command substitution is deprecated, use `$(...)` instead; `log_message="error copying files $(cat error.txt)"`

Answer (score 2):

```
`cat error.txt`
```

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, **but they may be removed during word splitting**.

To prevent word splitting, include the command substitution in double quotes.

```
echo $(printf 'a\nb\nc')
```

prints

```
a b c
```

while

```
echo "$(printf 'a\nb\nc')"
```

prints

```
a
b
c
```

(Prefer $(command) to old style  `command`).